# Fill array with variables (Maxima)

Tags: maxima

The following code is available

```
kol:2;
arg2:-3;
arg3:1/2;
mx0:makelist(concat(arg,i),i,2,kol+1);
```

which displays the result

```
[arg2,arg3]
```

Tell me, please, what needs to be changed so that the result is like this

```
[-3,1/2]
```

(i.e. the values of the variables themselves should be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
kol: 2;
arg2: -3;
arg3: 1/2;
mx0: makelist(concat(arg,i),i,2,kol+1), infeval;

                                         1
(%o4)                              [- 3, -]
                                         2
```

or use subscripts

```
kol:2;
arg[2]:-3;
arg[3]:1/2;
mx0:makelist(arg[i],i,2,kol+1);

                                         1
(%o4)                              [- 3, -]
                                         2
```

http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_singlepage.html#IDX252

http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_singlepage.html#IDX105

Comment: In general it is better to use explicit subscripts e.g. `arg[i]` instead of creating symbols in which the index is part of the name e.g. `arg_1`, `arg_2`. I think that wxMaxima displays `arg_k` the same as `arg[k]` but this is misleading; `arg_k` is not the same variable as `arg[k]`.